What is this snake movie?
I have a faint memory about a movie that I watched 15-20 years ago as a kid. Probably it should be a Hollywood movie. Now I'm looking for that movie for watch again. However I can't remember the name.
incomplete plot:
As per my remind, there was a young couple (boy/girl). And the boy's lower arm got bitten by a snake and movie continues. Eventually boy found out some snakes were hatched inside his hand and he used to cut a piece of his hand by an wall mounted emergency axe. However in the end, Both the girl and the boy was in a mud mash and a big snake came out from the boy's mouth, making the boy's jaws became apart.
Finally girl killed the boy by stabbing with a staff and a police office shot the boy with a shotgun.
Can anyone can remember this movie?

Well I didn't remember it, since I've never seen it, but Google did! 
It's Curse II: The Bite (1988).

Lisa (Jill Schoelen) and Clark (J. Eddie Peck) are two lovebirds who
  decide to drive across the Arizona desert  and run into a large group
  of snakes that have been terrorizing the towns in the area of a
  nuclear power plant.  When they stop to change a flat tire, a snake
  sneaks into their car and slithers around for a bit while they try to
  find a local service station to get their flat fixed.    
...  
When Clark and Lisa make it to a hotel for the night, Clark is bitten
  on the hand by the sneaky snake.  Luckily for them, salesman and
  amateur doctor Harry Morton (Jamie Farr) is there to administer an
  injection of snake venom antidote and save the day.  Later that night,
  Clark is still feeling the effects of the bite and is having a hard
  time dealing with the effects.   
...  
Clark's hand starts transforming into a snake and taking a mind of its
  own in the next few days.  He begins to change and he can't control
  it.  He beats a man in a bar bathroom after he tries to get into
  Lisa's pants, and the snake hand shoots down the mouth of a sheriff's
  deputy and pulls out his still beating heart after being taken into
  custody.  Now, Clark is on the run from the law, and Lisa has to try
  and protect him before he ends up hurting himself or more people. 
  Clark on the other hand (no pun intended) has bigger problems to deal
  with, besides his hand - now the "curse" is starting to take over his
  whole body, and he's desperate to find a solution for his problem.  

From triskaidekafiles.com

Clark runs off and stops at a nearby gas station, steals an axe, and
  ties his hand up in the bathroom, to try and emulate Ash removing his
  own evil hand.  It doesn't go so well as the snakehand has a mind of
  its own and keeps squirming away.  Like oh, a snake.
He bashes the snakehand into a mirror several times, which apparently
  knocks his hand out and that allows him to start hacking it off at the
  wrist.
...
Clark, or what remains of him, leans out of the pipe and pukes up more
  little snakes, until he coughs up one last giant one, which must have
  been his intestine at some point, because there's no other place that
  thing could have come from.
...
Lisa starts stabbing at the snakes with a wooden pole, for all the
  good that will do her.
...
Harry (not a cop but the police show up) actually gets the chance to
  save the day, as he fires off the fatal shotgun blast that kills the
  snake.


Is this some extension of Army of Darkness?  Ash removing an evil hand and all...

@Trish Ling Wow! Thanks, thats the movie. I've also Googled it several times however didn't come over. Actually it would be valuable to give any tips how did you search?

@inckka I just googled "movie snake came out of mouth". The first result was a horror movie forum thread where someone asking for an ID of a movie whose description sounded just like yours. I took the movie name from that thread and looked it up. Bit of luck is all.

@TrishLing Up-vote for all your internet sleuthing!
